# php variables and url and specifically ?'s

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to write a script which accepts a url such as rfile.php?url=https://example.com/file.php?alias=midlands how ever I want to be able to pass vairables over so it becomes r**file.php?url=https://example.com/file.php?alias=midlands?type=src** how ever **$type=$_GET['type'];** comes up as null.

I having checked $url=$_GET['url']; returns the full url string of **rfile.php?url=https://example.com/file.php?alias=midlands?type=src**

Clearly I can fix this but seperating the features I planned to use via the type vairable but I thought I would ask if any one knows a way to pull in that url including the **?alias=midlands** but stop at **?type=src** ?

**Example url** - rfile.php?url=https://example.com/file.php?alias=midlands?type=src

```
<?php
/*

*/
header("Pragma: No-Cache");

// Initialise variables
$url=NULL;
$type=NULL;

// Check auth is set
if (!isset($_GET['url']))
    {
    echo "Could not service your request. url was not set";
    }

// Check auth is set
if (!isset($_GET['type']))
    {
    echo "Could not service your request. type was not set";
    }

$url=$_GET['url'];
$type=$_GET['type'];

echo $url;
echo $type;

?>
```

Thanks

Terran

Comment: 2 question marks can't exist in a URL schema. Is type=src part of `rfile.php` or `example.com`?

Comment: Inadvisable workaround: [arg_separator.input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.input) (You should have a better rationale than being unaware of url escaping)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that what you want is to pass parameters and their values into your URL and grab them with `$_GET` method.

If this is what you are looking for, then you are having a typo in your example URL. The `?` tells the URL where to start looking for parameters. Each pair of parameter-value must be separated with character `&`. This means that the correct format of your URL in order to retrieve all those parameters is this one:

`rfile.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffile.php%3Falias%3Dmidlands&type=src`

Since you want to have a `url` as a parameter of the original `url` you should try to `urlencode` the parameter as above.

Probably your results will be:

`$_GET['url'] => https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffile.php%3Falias%3Dmidlands`

and

`$_GET['type'] => src`

Then u will have to run urldecode again on your `$_GET['url']` to grab the nested parameters. Hope I've helped.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back Alcueus - I will give this a go. T